# How to find a stolen android phone without internet connectivity?

Tags: google-play-store, lost-phone

Is there any app which could send me a text for the new sim and the number and with the help of the number can i send a text back to perform some remote locking features.
The point is when the phone is stolen and the thief has not switched on internet connectivity.
Are there any apps in Android market which could give some clue even then ?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Rameez! Having used the `lost-phone` tag (which of course perfectly fits), have you consulted [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info)? It contains some first-aid which most likely already answers your question. If not, come back here, [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/47718/edit) your question, and explain what you checked and where you're stuck.

Comment: [Prey](http://preyproject.com/) uses SMS messages for its control mechanism, but I don't think that's going to help you if there's a new SIM in the phone.

Comment: @AlE.: Actually it might , I have McAfee Wave Secure , which will immediately send sms with the no  inserted in sim . If you can control the mobile through SMS , then the duo combination can actually work , rite?